# multiple entities in EF 4.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am working on an MVC application which used data from different entities as well showing current date. I want to pass this data from controller to view. Should i create one entity to hold other entities ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a view Model and put everything you need in View in this viewmodel.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
     Entity1 Ent{get;set;}
     Entity2 Ent2{get;set;}
     DateTime CurrentDate{get;set;}  
}

public ActionResult index()
{
    MyViewModel model = new MyviewModel();
    model.Ent = new Entity1();
    model.Ent2 = new Entity2();
    model.CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
    return View(model) 
}
```

your view must now accept VieModel instead of db generated entity. in view you can access entities like

```
<%:Model.Ent1.SomeProperty%>
<%:Model.CurrentDate%>
<%:Model.Ent2.SomeProperty2%>
```

Comment: @adeel: where should i put the logic to get data from db and populate the entities/viewmodel in viewmodel ?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow you should put that logic in Action method of your controller. it does not mean that u access db objects directly in controller. you should create a layer that returns objects to calling code. plz have a look at repository pattern if you are not already familiar with it

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to create a ViewModel that will only hold the information specific for a View, not the whole entity.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really require a separate entity? What I am getting at is why not create an anonymous object which returns the entities required or just the properties required. A potential problem may occur by having an entity for every data scenario.